# High Latency and Thread Starvation Issues in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future, low-latency

I have a Spring Boot application with an API endpoint that pushes data to a Kafka topic. However, when the application experiences high load, it leads to significant latency issues, and many requests become thread-starved, eventually resulting in disconnections due to response timeouts.

The application utilizes `CompletableFuture` to push data asynchronously to Kafka. While this approach works well under normal circumstances, it struggles to handle the load efficiently, leading to degraded performance and thread starvation.

I have observed that during high load, only 70-80 threads are created, even though the maximum limit of threads is set to 300. This thread limitation further contributes to the latency and thread starvation problems.

Here is my controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/pushtokafka", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public EventResponse publishEventToKafka(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> map, @RequestBody(required = false) Payload payload) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            if (map.containsKey("abc")) {
                eventProducerService.pushtoKafka1(payload);
            } else {
                eventProducerService.pushtoKafka2(payload);
            }
        }, taskExecutor);

        return new EventResponse("success", "Successfully pushed to kafka");
    }
```

```
I have implemented custom thread pool
 @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(8); // set the core pool size
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20); // max pool size
        executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        executor. Initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

It's a blocker for us.

My spring boot versions is 2.2.6.RELEASE
my tomcat version is 9.0.65

I have changed these properties

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=300
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=120000
server.tomcat.accept-count=1000
server.tomcat.max-connections=-1
server.tomcat.min-spare-threads=200
```

after applying these properties , i am still getting the same issue.

I wanted to know why new threads is not getting created , if there is load .
[enter image description here][1]

kibana Transactions image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaCsC.png

Comment: Please show some code, configuration. Just describing it will not help in pointing to the issues. Basically your question is currently too broad. My initial guess would be wrong usage of `CompletableFuture` and starting your own threads instead of utilizing a threadpool. But as stated without seeing your configuration that is impossible to answer. Another thing Spring Boot 2.2 isn't really supported any more, I would suggest some upgrades as well.

Comment: I have added controller and thread pool executor .

Comment: Spring Boot already configures a `TaskExecutor` which I suggest to use. Setting a max threads with such a large queue size doesn't really do anything as threads will only be spawned if the queue is full. So I would suggest increasing the core pool size as well. And instead of a `CompletableFuture` I would simply use `taskExecutor.execute` or `taskExecutor.submit` (which will only work if you inject a `AsyncTaskExecutor` which the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is.

Comment: I have implemented that also , but no difference . Is there any issue in tomcat?

Comment: I don't see why there would be an issue in Tomcat, it doesn't even reach the size as it probably hits the queue limit or thread limit in your thread pool for the background tasks. Although I doubt the thread pool limit is reached as the queue is unbounded so I doubt anymore threads are being started. You state something about transactions overview in Kibana, what are transactions in this case? Are there transactional resources involved?

Comment: I have reverted the threads changes , now only 70-80 threads are creating .
Also the cpu and ram usage is very less . cpu -5% and ram 20 %
I have attached kibana screenshots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaCsC.png